# PHPMyAdmin has retained a bad query I typed as the default "browse" query

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Yesterday I typed a bad query into the SQL box of PHPMyAdmin.

Ever since, when I click on my database table in the bar on the left, or click the Browse button, my query is used as the default query. Or rather the part I typed at the end is added to every query.

I get an error dialog reading

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server 
version for the right syntax to use near 'offset1000 
LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1
```

which is my bad query. How can I get rid of this? Is there a cache with this query in it somewhere?

**Details**: PHPMyAdmin 4.0.10deb1ubuntu0.1 / Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) / Ubuntu 14.04.1 and yes, I've logged out and even rebooted the server.

Comment: Open whatever server interface you use and clear your browser cache and/or session data. Phpmyadmin stores historic queries into PHP sessions (these can become quite big files )

Comment: It can't be browser cache because it happens in an incognito browser and a different browser. Can it still be session data if those things are true? How can I clear session data?

Comment: Go into the server sessiond folder and delete the session.

Comment: See below for solution. As it still happened after logging out, rebooting the server and using two different browsers, I felt I'd proven to myself that it wasn't stored in a session.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer to this after a lot of searching.

PHPMyAdmin 4 has a table for this helpful feature.

It's in the database `phpmyadmin`, table `pma_table_uiprefs`. Stored against my username, that table and database was the bad query. I deleted it, which didn't help right away, but when I logged out and back in, it was gone.